# How mock logger created with the @Slf4j annotation?

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

`enter code here`I want to mock `log` property and then make a verification if `log.info(errorMessage, e);` was executed. The code is something like this.
(I'm using Mockito v4 and JUnit 5)

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoggerEx {

  // some properties ...
  private final LogEntryFactory logEntryFactory;
  private final HttpServletRequest request;

  public void logException(final Exception e, final HttpStatus status) {
      
    final Map<String, String> fields = getLogFieldsForLogRepo(status.value());

    if (e instanceof ExpectedException) {
        ((ExpectedException) e).getDetails()
          .forEach(detail -> createLogEntry(someStringHere, someStringHere, fields));
    } else {
        createLogEntry(someStringHere, e.getMessage(), fields);
    }
        final String errorMessage = String.format("Error causing %dxx response - %s",
                                          status.series().value(),
                                          "statusCode:" + status.value());
    if (status.is5xxServerError()) {
        log.error(errorMessage, e);
    } else if (e instanceof EofExpectedException) {
        log.debug(errorMessage, e);
    } else {
        log.info(errorMessage, e);
    }
  }
  
  // more methods ...

}
```

And my test is this ...

```
public class Test {

  @Mock
  private static Logger logger;

  @InjectMocks
  private LoggerEx exceptionLogger;
  private AutoCloseable closeable;
  @Mock private LogEntryFactory mockLogEntryFactory;
  @Mock private HttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest;
  @Mock private LogEntry mockLogEntry;

  // more properties 

  @BeforeAll
  public static void setUpLogger() {

    try(MockedStatic<LoggerFactory> loggerMock = mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class)) {
      loggerMock.when(() -> 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(logger);
    }
  }

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
  
    closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

    when(mockLogEntryFactory.createLogEntry(eq("SomeString")))
     .thenReturn(mockLogEntry);

    when(mockHttpServletRequest.getAttribute(
      eq("SomeRequestId")))
        .thenReturn("requestId");

    // more code ...
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void cleanUp() throws Exception {
      closeable.close();
  }

  @Test
  public void testSlf4j() {
    final ExpectedException e = new PersonalizedNotFoundException();
    exceptionLogger.logException((Exception) e, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    final String expectedLogMsg = "Error causing 4xx response - statusCode:404";
    verify(logger, times(1)).info(expectedLogMsg, (Exception) e);
  }

  // more test methods
}
```

an the error message says

```
LoggerEx > testSlf4j() FAILED
Wanted but not invoked:
logger.info(
    "Error causing 4xx response - statusCode:404",
    api.exceptions.PersonalizedNotFoundException: Job not found.
);

-> at LoggerEx(testSlf4j.java:someLine)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

What is happening here ? Maybe I'm missing something trying to mock `LoggerFactory`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to put content of `setUpLogger` at the end of `setup`

Comment: You are mocking a static using "scoped" mocking. The mock is only valid within the scope of the try-block, and you never call anything in the try-block.

Comment: Nutty question, is the unit test annotated with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` ?

Comment: @Guru_Clef were you able to find solution? I have tried many things but nothing seems to be work.